# R: Possible to extract groups of words from each sentence(rows)? and create data frame(or matrix)?

Tags: r, extract, text-mining

I created lists for each word to extract words from sentences, for example like this

```
hello<- NULL
for (i in 1:length(text)){
hello[i]<-as.character(regmatches(text[i], gregexpr("[H|h]ello?", text[i])))
}
```

But I have more than 25 words list to extract, that's very long coding. 
**Is it possible to extract a group of characters(words) from text data?**

Below is just a pseudo set.

```
words<-c("[H|h]ello","you","so","tea","egg")

text=c("Hello! How's you and how did saturday go?",  
       "hello, I was just texting to see if you'd decided to do anything later",
       "U dun say so early.",
       "WINNER!! As a valued network customer you have been selected" ,
       "Lol you're always so convincing.",
       "Did you catch the bus ? Are you frying an egg ? ",
       "Did you make a tea and egg?"
)

subsets<-NULL
for ( i in 1:length(text)){
.....???
   }
```

Expected output as below

```
[1] Hello you
[2] hello you
[3] you
[4] you so
[5] you you egg
[6] you tea egg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you have a long list of word-sets.  Here's a way to turn each wordset into a regex, apply it to a corpus (a list of sentences) and pull out the hits as character-vectors.  It's case-insensitive, and it checks for word boundaries, so you don't pull *age* out of *agent* or *rage*.

```
wordsets <- c(
  "oak dogs cheese age",
  "fire open jail",
  "act speed three product"
)

library(tidyverse)
harvSent <- read_table("SENTENCE
    Oak is strong and also gives shade.
    Cats and dogs each hate the other.
    The pipe began to rust while new.
    Open the crate but don't break the glass.
    Add the sum to the product of these three.
    Thieves who rob friends deserve jail.
    The ripe taste of cheese improves with age.
    Act on these orders with great speed.
    The hog crawled under the high fence.
    Move the vat over the hot fire.") %>% 
  pull(SENTENCE)
```

`aWset` builds the regexs from the wordsets, and applies them to the sentences

```
aWset <- function(harvSent, wordsets){
  # Turn out a vector of regex like "(?ix) \\b (oak|dogs|cheese) \\b"
  regexS <- paste0("(?ix) \\b (",
              str_replace_all(wordsets, " ", "|" ),
               ") \\b")
  # Apply each regex to the sentences
  map(regexS,
      ~  str_extract_all(harvSent, .x, simplify = TRUE) %>% 
         # str_extract_all return a character matrix of hits.  Paste it together by row.
        apply( MARGIN = 1, 
               FUN = function(x){
                    str_trim(paste(x, collapse = " "))}))
}
```

Giving us

```
aWset(harvSent , wordsets)
[[1]]
 [1] "Oak"        "dogs"       ""           ""           ""           ""           "cheese age" ""          
 [9] ""           ""          

[[2]]
 [1] ""     ""     ""     "Open" ""     "jail" ""     ""     ""     "fire"

[[3]]
 [1] ""              ""              ""              ""              "product three" ""              ""
```

Answer (score 3):

in base R, you could do:

```
regmatches(text,gregexpr(sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b",paste0(words,collapse = "|")),text))
[[1]]
[1] "Hello" "you"  

[[2]]
[1] "hello" "you"  

[[3]]
[1] "so"

[[4]]
[1] "you"

[[5]]
[1] "you" "so" 

[[6]]
[1] "you" "you" "egg"

[[7]]
[1] "you" "tea" "egg"
```

depending on how you want the results:

```
trimws(gsub(sprintf(".*?\\b(%s).*?|.*$",paste0(words,collapse = "|")),"\\1 ",text))
[1] "Hello you"   "hello you"   "so"          "you"         "you so"      "you you egg"
[7] "you tea egg"
```

Comment: `str_extract_all(text, str_c('\\b',words,'\\b', collapse = "|"))` using `stringr`.